# How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params) with stored procedure? EF Code First CTP5

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a stored procedure that has three parameters and I've been trying to use the following to return the results:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName", param1, param2, param3);
```

At first I tried using `SqlParameter` objects as the params but this didn't work and threw a `SqlException` with the following message:

> Procedure or function 'mySpName' expects parameter '@param1', which was not supplied.

So my question is how you can use this method with a stored procedure that expects parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I'm having trouble with code that works on 2008 in compat (90) mode, but when i run it against 2005 it fails with a syntax error.

Comment: @Gats - I had the same issue w/ SQL 2005. Add "EXEC" before the stored procedure name. I posted this info here for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403930/what-causes-incorrect-syntax-near-stored-procedure-name-in-ef-code-first-and

Answer (score 423, accepted):

You should supply the SqlParameter instances in the following way:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```

Comment: How would you make this method work with nullable types?  I tried this with nullable decimals, but when the decimals are null I get errors saying parameter is missing.  However, the method below mentioned by @DanMork works find.

Comment: Does passing `DbNull.Value` instead of nulls solve the problem?

Comment: You can also use the \@p# syntax to avoid using SqlParameter as in context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType("mySpName \@p0, \@p1, \@p2", param1, param2, param3).

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907.

(Note: had to use \@ to avoid user notifications, should be read without the backslash.)

Comment: If you are using DateTime parameters, you need to specify the parameter type too, not only name and value. For example: dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Invoice>("spGetInvoices @dateFrom, @dateTo", new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "dateFrom", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = startDate }, new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "dateTo", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, Value = endDate });
Another important thing is to respect the order of the parameters.

Comment: can you kindly check what I am doing wrong I have follow you guidline but no effect at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926598/passing-parameter-issue-from-entity-framework-to-store-procedure

Comment: is there myEntityType is mandatory, because i just want to Execute the query and get the `int` output

Comment: @devart Is there a way to clear Param's for repeated calls in EF ?

Comment: @singhswat could you please clarify your question? A test code will be appreciated.

Comment: As @FranciscoGoldenstein mentioned, it looks like, even when using named params, you need to pass them in the same Order they're defined in the SP. Has anyone else seen that?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use named parameters when calling the SP, rather than just relying on the Order. Seems problematic since to name the paramname you need to give @param1Name=... - but then make sure it doesn't get replaced/treated like a parameter

Comment: do we also need to dispose this command? I am using lots of these in the same way and now facing memory leak problems

Answer (score 134):

Also, you can use the "sql" parameter as a format specifier:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("mySpName @param1 = {0}", param1)
```

Comment: Had to up-vote this.  While it wasn't accepted as the answer, its a much easier to write solution than the one selected as answer.

Comment: This syntax concerns me a little bit.  Would it be susceptible to SQL injection?  I would assume EF is running  "EXEC mySpName @Param1 = ", and it would be possible to send "x' GO [malicious script]" and cause some problems?

Comment: @TomHalladay no risk of SQL injection - the method will still quote and escape the parameters based on their type, the same as the @ style params. So for a string parameter you would use "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email={0}" without quotes in your statement.

Comment: in my case we have lots of optional parameters for SP and did not work calls with SqlParameters but this format do the trick, just had to add 'EXEC' in the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: @ TomHalladay It actually have SQL injection problems (and also problem if your parameters have some simple quotes.)
@OnurTOPAL you can deal null values with myparam ?? "NULL"

Comment: This answer is useful if you have to specify parameters to a proc with optional parameters.  Example that doesn't work: `ProcName @optionalParam1 = @opVal1, @optionalParam2 = @opVal2`  Example that does work: `ProcName @optionalParam1 = {0}, @optionalParam2 = {1}`

Comment: Note that this solution may fall prey to [parameter type conversion problems](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already).  For consistent results always create the `SqlParameter` with an explicit `DbType`.

Comment: what will be the code for passing multiple parameter ?

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, I don't have an environment to test this right now, but I think the syntax for multiple params should be `context.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityType>("mySpName @param1 = {0}, @param2 = {1}", param1, param2);` (and don't forget you may need to add EXEC keyword depending on your environment).

Answer (score 72):

**This solution is (only) for SQL Server 2005**

You guys are lifesavers, but as @Dan Mork said, you need to add EXEC to the mix.  What was tripping me up was:

- 'EXEC '  before the Proc Name
- Commas in between Params
- Chopping off '@' on the Param
  Definitions (not sure that bit is required though).

:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<EntityType>(
    "EXEC ProcName @param1, @param2", 
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1), 
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2)
);
```

Comment: +1. Neither of the higher voted answers include `exec`, but I can confirm that I get an exception if I omit it.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting an error, added EXEC and error is gone. The weird part was if i did context.Database.SqlQuery<EntityType>("ProcName '" + param1 + "','" + param2 + "'"); it worked, but if I added parameters it didn't work until I added the EXEC keyword.

Comment: FYI: I do not require the `exec` keyword. +1 for the removal of the @ on the params, that always messes me up.

Comment: +1, I was missing EXEC and kept getting SqlExceptions with message: Incorrect syntax near 'procName'.

Comment: @AdrianCarr I can't edit my comment, so I will delete mine if you'll add some context to your comment + link "If procedure is not returning a result set, then a better fit would probably be the Database.ExecuteSqlCommand instead: your link"

Comment: If you're looking for a way to call a stored proc without return values, that can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122054/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-using-database-executesqlcommand-with-parameters

Comment: As Nathon Koop said I also didnot use exec and it worked for me. My answer above was the exact code that I use in my project which went to production. For me it works without even using exec keyword. I donot know why people down voted it... Please see this link.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx ... it works for me without exec...

Comment: @Ziggler are you on 2005 or newer?  The EXEC keyword has mainly been an issue for those of us going against 2005.

Comment: @ Tom Halladay.. Thanks for pointing it out. I was using EF4 with SQL SERVER 2008 R2, VS 2012 and C# with .NET 4.5. I will update my answer

Comment: Just a note, use context.Database.SqlQuery<Dummy>("EXEC sp_GetDummy"); for SQL Server..... and use context.Database.SqlQuery<Dummy>("CALL sp_GetDummy"); for MySQL stored procedure.

Comment: @TomHalladay can you please on help me with your wave i am getting error?can i say?

Answer (score 18):

```
return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
        new object[] { param1, param2, param3 });
```

Or

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
            new object[] { param1, param2, param3 })
        .ToList();
}
```

Or

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
    object[] parameters =  { param1, param2, param3 };

    return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
            parameters)
        .ToList();
}
```

Or

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{  
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
            param1, param2, param3)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: it is working for me for Assembly EntityFramework.dll, v4.4.0.0

Comment: if you are using using(var context = new MyDataContext()) then .ToList() is mandatory.

Comment: I spent some good amount of time to discover that .ToList() is mandatory to get correct result set.

Answer (score 11):

**Most answers are brittle because they rely on the order of the SP's parameters. Better to name the Stored Proc's params and give parameterized values to those.**

In order to use Named params when calling your SP, without worrying about the order of parameters

[Using SQL Server named parameters with ExecuteStoreQuery and ExecuteStoreCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035353/using-sql-server-named-parameters-with-executestorequery-and-executestorecommand)

Describes the best approach. Better than Dan Mork's answer here.

- Doesn't rely on concatenating strings, and doesn't rely on the order of parameters defined in the SP.

E.g.:

```
var cmdText = "[DoStuff] @Name = @name_param, @Age = @age_param";
var sqlParams = new[]{
   new SqlParameter("name_param", "Josh"),
   new SqlParameter("age_param", 45)
};

context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(cmdText, sqlParams)
```

Comment: It seems "params" is a reserved keyword, so I don't think you can use it like that. Otherwise this was a helpful answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ooXei1sh - fixed, using `sqlParams` variable

Comment: you _can_ prefix it with @ to use a reserved word, but you really _shouldn't_

Comment: Thanks, every other answer require parameters to be in the same sequence.

Answer (score 7):

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("exec GetNewSeqOfFoodServing @p0,@p1,@p2 ", foods_WEIGHT.NDB_No, HLP.CuntryID, HLP.ClientID).Single()
```

or

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(
    "exec GetNewSeqOfFoodServing @param1, @param2", 
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1), 
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2)
);
```

or

```
var cmdText = "exec [DoStuff] @Name = @name_param, @Age = @age_param";
var @params = new[]{
   new SqlParameter("name_param", "Josh"),
   new SqlParameter("age_param", 45)
};

db.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(cmdText, @params)
```

or

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>("mySpName {0}, {1}, {2}",
new object[] { param1, param2, param3 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this method:

```
var results = this.Database.SqlQuery<yourEntity>("EXEC [ent].[GetNextExportJob] {0}", ProcessorID);
```

I like it because I just drop in Guids and Datetimes and SqlQuery performs all the formatting for me.

Answer (score 1):

@Tom Halladay's answer is correct with the mention that you shopuld also check for null values and send DbNullable if params are null as you would get an exception like

*The parameterized query '...' expects the parameter '@parameterName', which was not supplied.*

Something like this helped me

```
public static object GetDBNullOrValue<T>(this T val)
{
    bool isDbNull = true;
    Type t = typeof(T);

    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null)
        isDbNull = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(default(T), val);
    else if (t.IsValueType)
        isDbNull = false;
    else
        isDbNull = val == null;

    return isDbNull ? DBNull.Value : (object) val;
}
```

(credit for the method goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter)

Then use it like:

```
new SqlParameter("@parameterName", parameter.GetValueOrDbNull())
```

or another solution, more simple, but not generic would be:

```
new SqlParameter("@parameterName", parameter??(object)DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did mine with EF 6.x like this:

```
using(var db = new ProFormDbContext())
            {
                var Action = 1; 
                var xNTID = "A239333";

                var userPlan = db.Database.SqlQuery<UserPlan>(
                "AD.usp_UserPlanInfo @Action, @NTID", //, @HPID",
                new SqlParameter("Action", Action),
                new SqlParameter("NTID", xNTID)).ToList();


            }
```

Don't double up on sqlparameter some people get burned doing this to their variable

```
var Action = new SqlParameter("@Action", 1);  // Don't do this, as it is set below already.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I was working with calling a stored procedure that takes two input parameters and returns 3 values using SELECT statement and I solved the issue like below in EF Code First Approach

```
 SqlParameter @TableName = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@TableName",
            DbType = DbType.String,
            Value = "Trans"
        };

SqlParameter @FieldName = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@FieldName",
            DbType = DbType.String,
            Value = "HLTransNbr"
        };


object[] parameters = new object[] { @TableName, @FieldName };

List<Sample> x = this.Database.SqlQuery<Sample>("EXEC usp_NextNumberBOGetMulti @TableName, @FieldName", parameters).ToList();


public class Sample
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public int NextNum { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**: It looks like with SQL SERVER 2005 missing EXEC keyword is creating problem. So to allow it to work with all SQL SERVER versions I updated my answer and added **EXEC** in below line

```
 List<Sample> x = this.Database.SqlQuery<Sample>(" EXEC usp_NextNumberBOGetMulti @TableName, @FieldName", param).ToList();
```

Comment: Please see below link. There is no need to use exec  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx