# Executing stored procedures from a DbContext

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

I have two simple stored procedures in SqlServer:

- `SetData(@id int, @data varchar(10))`
- `GetData(@id int)`.

`GetData` currently returns a single-row, single-column result set, but I could change it to be a proper function if needed.

What would be the best way to execute these from a `DbContext` instance?

If possible, I'd like to avoid having to do my own connection state management and/or exposing EF-specific types. I started by retrieving the `ObjectContext` and looking at the `Execute*` functions, but the documentation is pretty bad and lacking examples involving stored procedures.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
myContext.ExecuteNonQuery("SetData", id, data);
var data = myContext.ExecuteScalar<string>("GetData", id);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

DbContext offers these functions. Use:

```
IEumerable<...> result = myContext.Database.SqlQuery<...>(...)
```

to execute retrieval stored procedure and

```
int result = myContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(...)
```

to execute data modification stored procedure.

Comment: What about parameters? Do I have to do it as specified here or is there a shortcut? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-procedu/4874600#4874600

Comment: That is one way. It should also work without using `SqlParameter` - just pass values. I'm not sure if you don't have to refer to them by @p0, @p1, etc. when using values directly.

Comment: I ended up passing an anonymous object and converting it to SqlParameters internally.