# Return type error when i'm getting JSON as result when calling stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017-express

I was trying to get output by calling stored procedure to get result type in JSON format by calling the API.I have used Entity Framework and mapping was done to get values.But i'm getting the error.

i'm using visual studio 2019(entity framework 6,WEB API 2 using entity),SQL Server 2017

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/display_specifications/test/{tid}")]           
public string GetUsers(int tid)
{
  using (projectEntities users = new projectEntities())
  {
    return users.get_dynamicform(tid).FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{"field_id":1,"button_id":1,"label_name":"Full_Name","datatype":1,"ranges":60,"default_value":"null","field_width":20,"field_height":100,"label_width":10,
"rownumber":1,"sequence":1,"visibility":1,"placeholder":"Enter Full Name"}
```

ERROR:

> The type parameter 'System.String' in ExecuteFunction is incompatible with the type 'testingModel.get_dynamicform_Result' returned by the function for json

Comment: The method `get_dynamicform` returns a `List<string>`?

Comment: Please check your edmxs files.due to having a mix of old and new edmxs. Removing the old edmx allowed the new one to work or please check below link

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443092/the-type-parameter-in-execute-function-is-incompatible-with-the-type-returned-by

Answer (score 0):

In EF the stored procedure behind `get_dynamicform` is defined to return type `get_dynamicform_Result` which means it returns a collection. The use of `FirstOrDefault` means you will have zero or one instances of `get_dynamicform_Result`.

But `GetUsers` says it returns a string, and no conversion exists from `get_dynamicform_Result` to `string`.

You probably want to return a member property of `get_dynamicform_Result` rather than the whole object (but without the definition of `get_dynamicform_Result` we cannot be more specific). And also you need to handle the null case.