# What causes "Incorrect syntax near <stored procedure name>" in EF Code First and SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, code-first

The examples for System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery method I've found appear to work well with SQL 2008 R2 but do not appear to work with SQL 2005.

This call will work with SQL 2008 R2:

```
var myEntities = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("GetDataFromMySp @EntityId = {0}", entityId);
```

However, in SQL 2005 this statement will throw a SqlException with an error message of "Incorrect syntax near 'GetDataFromMySp'".

Comment: If you found the answer you may post the answer yourself and mark it as such, so it still works for future reference for others that may face the same issue.

Comment: @PedroC88 - I got an error that stated my rep was too low to post an answer immediately and that I had to wait 8 hours. Feel free to post the answer. :)

Comment: It's a Sunday: quiet day of the week. The question is 5 minutes old.

Comment: You may now remove the answer from the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution found by @Dan himself (couldn't post due to rep)

The solution I found to this issue was simply to add the keyword "EXEC" to the query:

```
var myEntities = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>("EXEC GetDataFromMySp @EntityId = {0}", entityId);
```

This solution fixed the issue with SQL Server 2005 and still worked with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4):

You only need EXEC if there are any statements before "GetDataFromMySp" in the batch.
A stored procedure name by itself should be OK.

I'd run SQL Profiler to see what is being actually being sent by EF.

Things like "prepared statements" issue extra commands as part of the batch in addition to your command text.

See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/bae30a3d-7a66-4aff-af99-6426cf0483b5

Comment: I don't disagree with you but the fact is:
1) Database.SqlQuery w/o EXEC worked in SQL 2008 R2 but not SQL 2005
2) adding "EXEC" to statement fixed SQL 2005 and didn't break SQL 2008. I haven't profiled this b/c it occurred in a controlled test environment which requires me to enlist the help of another team to profile. If I find the time, I'll recreate this in my virtual environment and post the trace.

Comment: Adding EXEC won't break anything. All this means is that some extra commands are sent for SQL Server 2005 before the stored proc call that aren't for SQL Server 2008+. Like I said, this is how SQL parses batches. The difference is in EF, not SQL Server which is behaving as expected...