# How to call a stored procedure from MVC that requires datetimes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm wanting to call this stored procedure with input parameters:

```
proc [dbo].[Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices] (

      @FinancialYearStartDate datetime = null
,      @FinancialYearEndDate datetime = null
```

Trouble with this is the way I usually call a stored proc from my code is:

```
return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>(string.Format("EXEC Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices @FinancialYearStartDate = '{0}', @FinancialYearEndDate = '{1}'", financialYear.StartDate.ToString(), financialYear.EndDate.ToString()));
```

So this isn't going to work because I've basically converted my datetimes to strings.

How the heck am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use **sql parameters**, basically like this:

```
var startDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearStartDate", dateTimeValueHere);
var endDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearEndDate", dateTimeValueHere);

return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices", startDate, endDate);
```

More info: [How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params) with stored procedure? EF Code First CTP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced)

Answer (score 0):

1. convert the date to a string with specific format.
2. use SQL code to convert it back to an sql datetime object.

When using sql server (microsoft):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
"convert(datetime, '{0}', 103)", financialYear.EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

edit: Ropstah's method is actually better, this is just the way I used to do it :P