# ASP.Net SQL String with Date String and SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005

I have a project that is used by several clients but for one of them using sql server 2005 wherever any code that runs a sql statement which includes a date like so:

```
" AND ABS.AbsenceDate = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
```

I get the error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

This only happens for this one client/server, if I copy the actual sql string created and execute it in Sql Server on this server it runs ok.  I created a test page to ensure the date string was correct and did indeed display as 2013-11-26 as expected. My assumption was that the app was sending the date as 2013-26-11 as this would cause the issue but then the test showed otherwise so leaves me stumped.

For info, this is on an English server so the regional setting is day/month/year and dates stored as year-month-day etc

Answer (score 2):

Don't concatenate strings to build your sql string but sql-parameters. The main reason is to prevent [sql-injection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but it can also prevent localization- or conversion issues like this.

```
string sql = @"SELECT Columns 
               FROM dbo.tableName
               WHERE ...
               AND ABS.AbsenceDate = @AbsenceDate";

using(var con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AbsenceDate",  DateTime.Today);
    con.Open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The values don't come from text boxes or anything people can enter into. I am using EF's ExecuteStoreQuery in places so can't use parameters.

Comment: @user1166905: I'm not familiar with it but this answer suggests that you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035353/using-sql-server-named-parameters-with-executestorequery-and-executestorecommand Apart from that, consider that today the user can't change it but maybe tomorrow. Also, as i've mentioned, parameters don't only prevent sql-injection but also other issues and they are more also more efficient (query does not change all the time, the systems may be able to re-use it).

Comment: Well, if EF can't do it, it sucks, I'd say and this alone would be a reason for me not to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind the added security, Sql Parameters would solve your problem automatically.

Is there a date part for that date or is it irrelevant ?

An example solution would be the following:

```
" AND ABS.AbsenceDate = Convert(DateTime, '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', 20) "'
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the issue and quite surprised at what the problem was.  I was able to run the sql ok in management studio but I was logged in using Windows Authentication.  I realised I should try with the account the app uses and when logged in as this I did get the error.

Turns out whoever set the account up had the Language set to British English.  I changed it to English and voila problem solved.

Comment: well, you didn't actually solve the problem. all code should work regardless of server cutlure. my advice would be to always use sql parameters and avoid implicit data type conversions