# What is my generic type/entity? (For Database.SqlQuery)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

I want to call Stored Procedures on my controller with C# + MVC 4 + Entity Framework 5.

### The problem

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced) that talk about "How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery(sql, params) with stored procedure? EF Code First CTP5" and that is exactly what I'm need.

In the topic we have the following code:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```

As you can see, there is a generic type (?) called `myEntityType` and I do not know who is my entity type.

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and all of my CRUD was generated by him.

### Details

What I want it is simple (I guess): display the return of procedure in my view. The above's code is what I have on ProductsController:

```
//
// GET: /Products/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.bm_products.ToList());
}
```

I want to display the return in this method.

### What I have

Maybe `myEntityType` is `bm_products`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myEntityType`, or `TElement`, is the type of object that should be created to house the result. If your procedure did this:

```
SELECT FieldA FROM table
```

then you'd need a class like this:

```
public class myEntityType
{
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
}
```

where `myEntityType` is the class name for the type -that's up to you.

Comment: Are you right, Michael. My Entity is `bm_products`. The problem now is the parameters — doesn't seem to working. "The name 'parameter1' doesn't exist in the current context.". I will update my main topic, by the way thanks about your help!

Comment: @chiefGui, I don't know what `mySpName` returns. But what I'm saying is that the `myEntityType` you're asking about is the class that will house the results so it needs to map to what is `SELECT`ed from the stored procedure.

Comment: But Michael, you is right! `bm_products` is returning me the fields that I need to show.

Comment: @chiefGui, so are you saying it's working now that you put `bm_products` in place of `myEntityType`?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelPerrenoud! =)

Comment: @chiefGui, fantastic! I'm glad I could be of assistance. Please remember to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I just had no marked as resolved yet because I'm still with the little problem of parameters. By the way, now I have marked already — you answered my question and that's what matters. Thank you, Michael.

Comment: @chiefGui, if you're having a problem with the parameters add another question and let me know and I'll stop by and answer it.

Comment: Ok @MichaelPerrenoud, I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

What about myEntityType when you are calling a stored procedure which has two output parameters called @OFirstName and @OLastName both of type varchar in a stored procedure. Those two output parameters are not columns of any table.