# must declare the scalar variable '@custid' using dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to execute stored procedure from bcontext.Database.SqlQuery using EF5.

It is throwing an error `must declare the scalar variable '@custid'`

```
  var results = _MiscContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
              "exec sp_GetStaff @custid",
              customerNumber).ToList<int>();
```

SP returns `1` if customerNumber is staff otherwise it return `empty` row.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetStaff]
    @custid varchar(12)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
1 AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Staff] with (nolock)
WHERE [CUSTOMER_ID] = @custid


END
```

How to manage this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you're using named parameters, you have to specify the matching name for the parameter you're passing.

```
var results = _MiscContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
    "exec sp_GetStaff @custid",
    new SqlParameter("custid", customerNumber)).ToList<int>();
```

Comment: You are awesome, Microsoft are not, see here where they claim you can simply add the parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. Also, if you get a weird error when you try the above fix, check the namespaces used. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705767/sqlparametercollection-only-accepts-non-null-sqlparameter-type-objects-not-str

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var results = _MiscContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
              "exec sp_GetStaff {0}",
              customerNumber).ToList();
```

Comment: This loses the performance and security benefits of a parameterized query.