# Stored procedure expects parameter that is being passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

From the following code I get the error that `@StartDate` is not supplied, however stepping through the two date range parameters have a valid value:

```
SqlParameter[] ps = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@StartDate", startDate),
    new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate)
};

List<AttendanceReportViewModel> res = db.Database.SqlQuery<AttendanceReportViewModel>(Local.queries["AttendanceReport"], ps).ToList();

return res;
```

The stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAttendanceReport]
    @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    exec [REMOTE_SRV].LWD.dbo.ReportAttendance_sp @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;
END
```

Everything works fine when I execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio but doesn't from within the application.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter you are referecing to ?

Comment: Both params are `DateTime`

Comment: Both TSQL and .NET point of view ?

Comment: Yes, I'll post the proof.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params) with stored procedure? EF Code First CTP5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced)

Comment: I'm not using code first, I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: Just to remove a stupid possibility... is SSMS and the Application both talking to the exact same database?

Comment: `@StartDate = @StartDate` you prob. should consider renaming the parameter what you accept.

Comment: @freefaller the SP above calls another on a linked server. I've checked all params and they have a value and are of type `datetime`

Comment: @lee what are the values that you're passing?  DateTime.Min is not the same in .NET and SQL Server.

Comment: I'm passing .NET `DateTime` vars as params to a local SP that accepts `DATETIME`. I've not had this data type problem before, so I expect they're compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Local.queries["AttendanceReport"]` looks something like this:

```
Local.queries["AttendanceReport"] = "yourProc @StartDate, @EndDate"
```

Then try this:

```
List<AttendanceReportViewModel> res = db.Database.SqlQuery<AttendanceReportViewModel(
    Local.queries["AttendanceReport"], 
    new SqlParameter("StartDate", startDate),
    new SqlParameter("EndDate", endDate)
).ToList();
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I was also missing a comma between my params.