# Can I have a where clause that works on a grandchild in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have three tables that are each connected with a primary key and foreign key such as TestId and UserTestId etc.

```
Exam > Test > UserTest
```

It's my understanding I can use LINQ to get the data from these like this:

```
        var exams = _examsRepository
       .GetAll()
       .Where(q => q.SubjectId == subjectId)
       .Include(q => q.Tests.Select(t => t.UserTests))
       .ToList();
```

This will select all the exams, Tests for the exams and UserTests for those Tests where SubjectId == subjectID

Is there any possible way I could further limit this so that it only showed the data for when the UserTests had a UserId of 123?

If the answer is no then should I rewrite this LINQ to first go to the _userTestsRepository and then work in the other direction up instead of down?

Comment: you could use subqueries here

Comment: Cris - Can you give an example. I did try the answer but it gives an error when run.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, which framework are you using? Is this EF, if so, which version?

Comment: @Chris Ballard - Sorry I did not provide enough information. We are using EF6 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085462/conditional-include-in-linq-to-entities) they offer a solution which does what you want but in my opinion feels a little like a hack.
Alternatively you could step away from include statements and do a manual join, you can apply as many filters on sub tables as you like that way.

Could look a lil like this :

```
var data = (from ex in context.exams
           join t in context.tests on ex.Id equals test.ExamID
           join ut in context.userTests on t.Id equals ut.TestId
           where ut.UserId = 123
           select new {ex, ut}).ToList();
```