# How to return values to Web API Controller from a stored procedure in DBContext

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am trying validate values to be inserted into SQL from Web API 2 and Repository Pattern.  The database has a stored procedure for checking the values passed (foreign key dependencies etc).  The stored proc returns a -1 for each value that is invalid or else isValid=true.  I need to pass the param that is invalid to my repository/controller so i can return an http response message to the end user indicating what was invalid. Here's what I have so far in my DBContext.  How can I do this?

```
public void Api_Event_Prefs_InsertUpdateCheck(int individualID, int eventID) {

        var p_PrefID = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@PrefID", Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null, Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput };
        var p_individualID = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@IndividualID", Value = individualID, Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput };
        var p_eventID = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@eventID", Value = eventID, Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput };
        var p_IsValid = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@IsValid", Value = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean.False, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec dbo.Api_Event_Prefs_InsertUpdateCheck @PrefID, @IndividualID OUT, @EventID OUT, @IsValid OUT", p_PrefID, p_individualID, p_eventID, p_IsValid);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Database.SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117(v=vs.113).aspx), which lets you execute an stored procedure, or any other query, and get the results of the execution.

`ExecuteSqlCommand` is only useful for running queries from which don't need to return the data (for example updates or DDL sentences).

Comment: OK, thank you.  Can you give an example of how to use it with the above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced