# SOA for old Application

Tags: c#, rest, architecture, domain-driven-design, automatic-ref-counting

I have one project which have 8 modules.
some of then is developed in VB.net,asp.net,C# windows forms,asp.net 
Now we have situation that we are not able to manage this modules.
so need to re-write this application using new technology like aps.net mvc,
web api etc.
             But we have big problem we have lot of logic in **stored procedure** 
(80% ~ 90%) the we are not come out of sp. we are using EF for database Communication but we are not able to design domain Model in persistence layer 
and we need DDD (domain driven design) 
So how we design application architecture so this will support Web,desktop application and also for Mobile. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure business logic is inherently not going to be DDD.  If you are insisting that you keep stored procedures, then you will not get DDD.

That being said, wrapping web api wrappers around stored procedures should allow you to leverage them in the various ways you specify:

[How to return values to Web API Controller from a stored procedure in DBContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549456/how-to-return-values-to-web-api-controller-from-a-stored-procedure-in-dbcontext)

http://sivakumarparameswaran.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-invoke-stored-procedure-in-web.html