# Unable to call "select" stored procedure using EF6 code first from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This code is failing with the error: "Must declare the scalar value @prodID". Any suggestions?

```
using (var ctx = new StewieDataModel())
    {
        string productID = "81";

        var techData = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<TechData>("dbo.usp_DS_GetTechData @prodID", productID).ToList();
     }
```

Here's the model:

```
namespace DatasheetData
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class StewieDataModel : DbContext
{
    public StewieDataModel()
        : base("name=StewieConnectionString")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Here's the class I want to populate:

```
namespace DatasheetData
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("usp_DS_GetTechData")]
public partial class TechData
    {

        public string TestCategory { get; set; }

        public string TestName { get; set; }

        public string TestResultLabel { get; set; }

        public string TestResult { get; set; }

        public string TestMethod { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's how I call it successfully in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_DS_GetTechData]
        @prodID = "81"

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

The SSMS results are four columns of VarChar data:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter as a `SqlParameter` object. Something like this should work:

```
var techData = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<TechData>(
        "dbo.usp_DS_GetTechData @prodID", 
        new SqlParameter("prodID", productID)
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: That fixed the initial problem but I get zero values returned now when several are expected. Not sure how to troubleshoot that. Thanks.

Comment: Run SQL Profiler and see exactly what is being called against the database.

Comment: I'm getting results now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A shorthand alternative to DavidG's correct answer is:

```
var techData = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<TechData>(
              "dbo.usp_DS_GetTechData @prodID = {0}", productID).ToList();
```

as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6403879/381082).