# How can I call a stored procedure where my code is using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call the below stored procedure to display a list of products with a certain product type.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filterListSP
    @productType varchar (25)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ProductId, Description, Price 
    FROM
        tblProduct 
    WHERE
        ProductType = @productType
END
GO
```

And this is the code calling the SP:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = naafiDbEntity.Database.SqlQuery<tblProductType>
    ("filterListSP @productType", cboFilter.SelectedValue).ToList();
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@productType"

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced

Comment: It took me (and I guess @MarcoHurtado) about 10 seconds to Google this and reach the same question, how come you didn't find it?

Comment: I apologise i'm new to coding and have tried searching for the answer on google, however from that other question I now receive this error: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'NaafiDatabaseModel.tblProductType'. A member of the type, 'ProductType', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: Well I suggest that your model class doesn't match the return type of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

define in a function in your dbcontext like this.
then make the call through this way 
eg: `dbcontext.SP_Insert(data,value);`

```
            public virtual int SP_Insert(string productType, ObjectParameter retValue)
            {
                var xmlDataParameter = xmlData != null ?
                    new ObjectParameter("productType", xmlData) :
                    new ObjectParameter("productType", typeof(string));

                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SP_Insert", xmlDataParameter, retValue);
            }
```

Here the stored procedure is SP_Insert

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I managed to work it out eventually.

This is what I amended my code to

```
    string result = cboFilter.SelectedValue.ToString();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = naafiDbEntity.filterListSP(result);
```