# Execute stored procedure in ASP.NET MVC and LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm very new to ASP.NET, so this may be a very basic question. Anyway, I want to execute a stored procedure on a server. I'm using, as in the heading mentioned, ASP.NET MVC. Currently it is possible to query the whole table:

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetLaptopsJson()
{
    Laptop[] laptops = context.GetTable<Laptop>().ToArray();
    return Json(laptops, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetLaptopsJson',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json' 
       })
       .success(function (result) {
            $('#search_result').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i <= (result.length - 1); i++)
            {
                add_result(result[i].Id, result[i].Price);
            }
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) { 
             alert(status);

        });
```

Model:

```
[Table(Name = "Laptop")]
public class Laptop
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

If I change the controller to following, it returns nothing:

```
var laptops = context.ExecuteQuery<Laptop>(@"exec [dbo].[sp_Select_Laptop]");
```

Also if I change the type from laptop to object, it returns nothing. This leads me to the fact, that I misunderstood something fundamental.

Thanks in advance guys!

**EDIT1:**

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_Select_Laptop]
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [ID], [Name], [Price]
    FROM 
        [dba].[dbo].[Laptop]
GO
```

Comment: Can you provide `[dbo].[sp_Select_Laptop]` code, also are you sure the SP itself returns needed values?

Comment: yes, it returns the needed values. tested in the ssm-studio.

Comment: Use `context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(...)`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Maarten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261050/maarten) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873607/how-to-use-dbcontext-database-sqlquerytelementsql-params-with-stored-proced).

Following changes are necessary:

Controller:

```
DbContext dbcontext;
public HomeController()
{
    this.dbcontext = new DbContext(Connections.connection);
}

var laptops = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<Laptop>(@"exec [dbo].[sp_Select_Laptop]");
```