# sp_executesql calling EXEC does not work with optional parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm working with SQL Server 2014 and I'm trying to execute a (dynamic) stored procedure from entity framework.

My stored procedure has the following input parameters:

```
@Username          NVARCHAR(100),
@Number            DECIMAL,
@PageIndex         INT = 1,
@PageSize          INT = 20,
@Field1            NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
@Field2            NVARCHAR(60) = NULL,
@Field3            NVARCHAR(60) = NULL,
@Field4            NVARCHAR(60) = NULL,
@Field5            NVARCHAR(60) = NULL,
@Field6            NVARCHAR(60) = 'ABC',
@Field7            NVARCHAR(4)  = 'ABC',
@IsCountOnly       BIT = 0,
@IsFilterOnly      BIT = 0
```

EF generates the following query (captured via SQL profiler) based on the parameters I've added to my array but note that I'm only adding the ones I need since most of them are optional.

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'EXEC MySp @Username, @Number, @IsCountOnly', 
N'@Username nvarchar(100), Number decimal(6,0), @IsCountOnly bit', 
@Username=N'me@mycompany.com', @Number=12345, @IsCountOnly=1
```

When I pass the @Username, @Number which are both compulsory and then pass the @IsCountOnly, my stored procedure gets executed but it returns the wrong results as it seems to treat the value passed via @IsCountOnly as @PageIndex rather than @IsCountOnly.

Note that if I call EXEC directly in the `SQL Server Management Studio`:

```
EXEC    [dbo].[MySp]
@Username = N'me@mycompany.com',
@Number = 12345,
@IsCountOnly = 1
GO
```

It works as expected.

To test whether this was the problem, I included all the parameters in the `exec sp_executesql N'EXEC ...` and it worked as expected but it just seems like an overkill having to defined all the parameters when only a few are needed in some scenarios.

Is this a bug in SQL when working with `exec sp_executesql` and `EXEC` or am I doing something wrong??

Thanks.

UPDATE-1:

Note that when I say it worked as expected when passing all the parameters, that's not entirely true as when I pass null for the optional parameters, it's not actually using the default values provided which to some extend makes sense but it means I would have to pass the correct defaults in my `.NET` project rather than via SQL which is just not ideal.

Comment: You're doing it wrong (sorry). Use `EXEC MySp @Username = @Username, @Number = @Number, @IsCountOnly = @IsCountOnly` instead. It's confusing, but your syntax actually passes parameters by ordinal position, just filling those ordinal values with the parameters of the parameterized `EXEC` statement itself.

Comment: None of the parameters are specifying which parameter they are passing, so they are based on ordinal position, not name of the variable. The 3rd parameter in your SP is `@PageIndex`, so `@IsCountOnly` (which is the 3rd value passed), will be treated as the value for `@PageIndex`; and the remainder will have their default value. This seems like a mapping error in your application code.

Comment: *"when I pass null for the optional parameters, it's not actually using the default values provided"* A default value for a parameter is used when the parameter is omitted, not when `NULL` is passed. `NULL` is still a value, just an unknown one.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you were bang on! Quickly modified my function that creates the field list for my optional fields to include the same field and it worked immediately!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named parameters:

```
N'EXEC MySp @Username=@Username, @Number=@Number, @IsCountOnly=@IsCountOnly''
```

Comment: I'm not generating this code. Entity framework is and this is my problem. as it is generating the query as 'exec sp_executesql N'EXEC....' as mention in question which is causing the problem. This is the call I have in my data layer: `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery("EXEC MySP @Username, @Number, " + optionalParameters, parameterList.ToArray())` where the optional parameters are just additional @Field being set and the parameterList contains an array of SqlParameters.

Comment: I'm going to try to call it via .SqlQuery and see what happens just by hardcoding it first and not pass the parameters array as it is optional

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. as sp_executesql expects parameters to be passed.

Comment: @Thierry: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4873607/4137916) for more on how EF rolls specifically.

Comment: As @JeroenMostert stated, using name parameters is the solution. Thanks again.