# Dynamic Stored Procedure and EF4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have a dynamic stored procedure with two parameters and I can`t add to the model because it has no columns defined.

Any idea how I can get the data into a DataSet.

Tanks

Comment: Are you referring to code first in EF 4.1? Can you post your code and give more details of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you were after, so I have assumed that you don't know how to pass parameters to stored procedure in EF4.1 Code first.

```
SqlParameter customerIdParam = new SqlParameter("@customerId", customerId);
Customer customer = context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("P_FindCustomer @customerId", customerIdParam).FirstOrDefault();
```

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845246/does-entity-framework-code-first-support-stored-procedures) a while ago.

Comment: I think what Andres is saying is that the result set has dynamic column (names or count?), so they can't map the results back to a fixed model (in your example, "Customer").