# How can I check existence of a stored procedure and view and function in seed method of Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application and Entity Framework code first. I use a stored procedure and views and functions for my report section in my project. Then I want to after updating my database these stored procedure and views and functions dos not clean and drop after updating. I use this way and I want check if not exist this object then create it  but when I run this code Nuget package manger said 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

I don't know what is wrong in my code any tips or trick would be welcome I haven't many time to waiting for this question please send me answer immediately thanks in advance

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'stp_Report1-2')
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Report1-2] 
    @startDate char(10),
    @endDate char(10),
    @ContractorTitle nvarchar(100)

    AS
BEGIN
    -- setting the smallest date to filter
    if(@startDate is null) SET @startDate='1300/01/01'
    --setting the end date the current date if it has not been set
    if(@endDate is null)SET @endDate=dbo.GetShamsiDate( GetDate())
    if(@ContractorTitle is null)SET @ContractorTitle=''
    SELECT *
    from Raja.dbo.[Report1-2]
       where [contractor_title]=@ContractorTitle and export_date between @startDate and @endDate
       Order by export_date desc


END

");
```

and when I use this code instead of up code, I get this error in Nuget

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Code:

```
 context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'stp_Report1-2')
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Report1-2] 
    @startDate char(10),
    @endDate char(10),
    @ContractorTitle nvarchar(100)

    AS
BEGIN
    -- setting the smallest date to filter
    if(@startDate is null) SET @startDate='1300/01/01'
    --setting the end date the current date if it has not been set
    if(@endDate is null)SET @endDate=dbo.GetShamsiDate( GetDate())
    if(@ContractorTitle is null)SET @ContractorTitle=''
    SELECT *
    from Raja.dbo.[Report1-2]
       where [contractor_title]=@ContractorTitle and export_date between @startDate and @endDate
       Order by export_date desc


END

");
```

and if I use this code these error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@endDate".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@endDate".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ContractorTitle".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ContractorTitle".
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@ContractorTitle".

Code:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'stp_Report1-2')

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Report1-2] 
    @startDate char(10),
    @endDate char(10),
    @ContractorTitle nvarchar(100)

    AS
BEGIN
    -- setting the smallest date to filter
    if(@startDate is null) SET @startDate='1300/01/01'
    --setting the end date the current date if it has not been set
    if(@endDate is null)SET @endDate=dbo.GetShamsiDate( GetDate())
    if(@ContractorTitle is null)SET @ContractorTitle=''
    SELECT *
    from Raja.dbo.[Report1-2]
       where [contractor_title]=@ContractorTitle and export_date between @startDate and @endDate
       Order by export_date desc
END
");
```

Comment: You can execute only **one** command at a time with *ExecuteSqlCommand*.

Comment: then how can i get it to one command ?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809485/how-can-i-define-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: You have to send the two commands separately. First the check, and in your C# code decide whether the create command should be executed.

Comment: thanks for your answer i separate existence code and creating store procedure but i don't know how can i return true or false when this store procedure exist then by if statement i check it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check that doing the following:

```
protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
{
   if (context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = @uspName",
                                       new SqlParameter("@uspName", "your stored procedure name")).Single() == 0)
    {
        -- // On the example below I am using a resource file named StoredProcedures, which has the t-sql
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseScripts.StoredProcedures.your stored procedure name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First execute this statemment:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'stp_Report1-2'
```

It will Return 0 or 1.

Then in Your C# code check the Return value, if it is 0, run Your create stored procedure code.

Comment: thanks for your answer i use this code for checking the existence of procedure

Comment: var ExistVW4 = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT exists (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name ='Report1-4')
        THEN 0

        ELSE 1 
    END ");
    if (ExistVW4.First() == 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to return the result of the `IF EXISTS` call to C# by *always* doing a `DROP` and `CREATE` and you can avoid the

> should be the first statement in a batch file

error by putting the sql inside an `EXEC` command:

```
Sql(EXEC('IF  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM sys.objects 
                      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Foos')
                      AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
             DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Foos')

Sql(EXEC('Create PROCEDURE dbo.Foos As etc'))
```

The problem with the GO statement is that

> it is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the
>   sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor

References:

[Issue with Sql GO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13591067/150342)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)