# How to execute a row sp with DbDatabase.SqlQuery()

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using **Entity Framework 4.3.1 code-first**. Is there any way to execute a stored procedure with parameters and get it's result value as a scalar? I find this method in **DbContext**:

```
public IEnumerable SqlQuery(Type type, string sql, params object[] parameters)
```

but I don't know how to use it. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845246/does-entity-framework-code-first-support-stored-procedures