# Code First call stored procedure to return multiple results

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Code First in a project. The project is half done. I need to call a stored procedure to return multiple results (3 selects). My research tells me that it is not supported in Code First. What options do I have? Changing the project to use Model first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roman from MSFT answered my question. He blogged about it here:
http://romiller.com/2012/08/15/code-first-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results/

I am sure a lot of people are having the same problem. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you break the sproc into 3? I think you would have a problem returning multiple entities from one query. Otherwise, would this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4845591/1572123

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It would take 3 trips back to database. Performanc would take a big hit.

Comment: Good point. Since I obviously can't help you, I'll close by suggesting a _terrible_ hack whereby you create a composite POCO that contains 3 `IList<T>` of types that correspond to each of the 3 result sets. You could then use `.Include()` for each when retrieving the parent to return all 3 lists at once. Shoddy, I know. ;) Good luck, Frank.