# EF reverse engineering code first and stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, reverse-engineering, edmx

Is there a way to auto-generate a results model when using Entity Framework Reverse engineering code-first? It would certainly make things more accurate to have a result object created right from the stored-procedure rather than "by hand".

I know there is a way to do this with an edmx file from a database (a/k/a "model") first approach (e.g.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716703%28v=vs.100%29.aspx 
).

I use Visual Studio 2010 (VS 2010) with .Net framework 4 with MVC 3 EF 4.1.0.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 if that helps answer the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stack overflow question has more information about this:

[Does Entity Framework Code First support stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845246/does-entity-framework-code-first-support-stored-procedures)

Apparently, this works with EF 6 and VS 2012 or later.