# Entity Framework - code first, call complex stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework code first approach. I want to implement a complex [with INNER JOIN, FUNCTION etc.] stored procedure using this approach. I have gone through many question on SO but I get more confused after reading these questions.

**What I have done**

I first successfully created database using code first approach.  As per my research on google, I created a stored procedure with an `INNER JOIN` in my database.

Then I created class matching with resultant columns from the stored procedure. Then I added this class to my `ApplicationDbContext` class like this

```
public DbSet<AllInfo> allInfos { get; set; }
```

Then in my APIController I call stored procedure like this

```
var registerUser = db.allInfos.FromSql($"SP_GetInfo").ToList();
```

but I get error saying `AllInfo` has no `key` defined. Also `AllInfo` table is added to database because I have added reference in `ApplicationDbContext`.

**My questions**

1. Why does `AllInfo` class needs a key when I want this class just to show information retrieved from the stored procedure?
2. If I have to create class for each stored procedure, then there will be so many classes in my project. Is my understanding correct ?
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516685/5509235) link says DO NOT create SP when using stored procedures. Then what is the method to call complex queries ?

Kindly help with my confusion.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my query. it is not as much complex though but further queries might be complex

```
SELECT 
    a.UserId,
    a.FullUserName,
    a.BirthDate,
    a.BloodGroup,
    a.ContactNo,
    a.Email,
    a.Gender,
    ISNULL(dbo.Fn_FetchEducationInfo(a.UserId), '-NA-') AS Education
FROM 
    RegisterUsers AS a
```

Function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_FetchEducationInfo]
    (@Id VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Education AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT
        @Education = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Education +',' 
                            FROM Tbl_Education as edu 
                            INNER JOIN OPersonMEducations opme ON edu.EduId = opme.EduId 
                            INNER JOIN RegisterUsers RU ON RU.UserId = opme.Id
                            WHERE RU.UserId = @Id
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    FROM 
        RegisterUsers AS a

    --print @Education
--'UPB005' 
    RETURN @Education
END
```

Comment: If the query is complex and cannot be handled by Entity Framework, I see no reason why you should not use a stored procedure.  If you show us the query it might help to give you a better answer.

Comment: @ywwy please see my edit. I want to use stored procedures but I don't know the exact process of implementing it in code-first approach. Everybody tells a different thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

Comment: In EF Core 3.0  model can contain keyless entity types, which can be used to carry out database queries against data that doesn't contain key values,use  .HasNoKey() method call, more detail here :[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types)

Answer (score 0):

I would need to understand what your final intention is (not sure what you need the xml for), but from the stored procedure you are showing us, I would say that you do not need a stored procedure to do this selection.  Create an 'Education' entity and add a List of 'Education' to your 'RegisterUsers' entity.

```
public class RegisterUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullUserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    //Extra properties

    public IList<Education> Educations { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
    [Key]
    public int EduId { get; set; }

    //Extra properties
} 



public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<RegisterUser> RegisterUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<Education> Educations { get; set; }
}

// Add the needed conditions here
var registerUser = ctx.RegisterUsers.Include(x => x.Educations);
```

Comment: But I have one more class like Education. How can I include it ? I specified here only two classes to give you an idea

Comment: @Monica This depends on how the extra class relates to the existing ones.  Learning the syntax takes some time, but I think it is worthwhile.  I am still learning myself :).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you adding the class to ApplicationDbContext. If you add a class to ApplicationDbContext, it would need a key so that the corresponding table have a key.
Also, since you already have the class, remove it from the ApplicationDbContext and just call the stored procedure.

```
var variableName= context.Database.SqlQuery<ClassName>("EXEC storedProcedureName @ParameterName_1, @ParameterName_n",
                   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ParameterName_1", ParameterValue_1),
                   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ParameterName_n", ParameterValue_n)
                   ).ToList();
```

Then you can use the object however you want. Remember it returns a list so don't forget to add index when you want to access the value. If you are expecting just one row from the stored procedure, you can use the `SingleOrDefault()` extension instead of the `ToList()` so you won't need to use the indexing.

UPDATE:

Lets say for example you have a stored procedure that return a row with three fields *Field_1, Field_2, Field_3*.
You also have 2 parameters you pass into the stored procedure *Parameter_1, Parameter_2* and their values is *ParameterValue_1, ParameterValue_2*

You can create a class without adding it to the DbContext. They are called ViewModels. So you have

```
public class WhateverNameYouWant
{
    public string Field_1{ get; set;}
    public string Field_2{ get; set;}
    public string Field_3{ get; set;}
}
```

Then run the code

```
var variableName= context.Database.SqlQuery<WhateverNameYouWant>("EXEC storedProcedureName @Parameter_1, @Parameter_2",
                   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ParameterName_1", ParameterValue_1),
                   new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ParameterName_2", ParameterValue_2)
                   ).ToList();
```

The join is done in the database, return an object you can display however you want. Also, if you know for sure the record is going to return just one result, you can use the `SingleOrDefault()` extension so you don't need to worry about indexes.

To answer your questions, 
1. Yes you would need to create a class for objects returned from stored procedures to be able to use them. It is the same thing with model cos if you think about it, you create a model class for all tables and when you query data from the database, the result is injected into the model.

2. Well technically true but you should look to redesigning your model if you are having to get a lot of your data away from EF. If the model is designed well, there shouldn't be too much need to do complex joins away from EF. Using the `Include` extension gets a lot of joins done but then again, you have to properly design the models with correct mappings.
3. Again, the reason for EF is so we don't have to manually retrieve data from the database by writing SQL. However, this goes back to point number 2, you can design complex statements manually but if you are having to do it all the time, you should look at the model design again.

Comment: What would be the `classname` when I am joining two or more tables ?