# MVC database first EF imported SPs returning Complex types how and where to call it

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, procedures

I'm new to  MVC and I use  DB first approach and Entity Framework. I have imported my custom Stored Procedures that are returning mostly complex types. So far OK.
I see also code - object created in `Context.cs`. Now where (in a Controller?) and how to call stored procedures and also add related view? I don't prefer `linQ` or raw `sql` query methods

An example of SP is:

```
create proc Test1
@company_name varchar(50)
)
as
(

select * from Profile
where greek_name like '%' + @company_name + '%'
```

Comment: in DB-first approach all your SPs are added as a methods to EF context.

Answer (score 0):

You can call stored proc wherever you need, mostly in service layer, why? coz service layer is usually stateless and having separate layer which is stateless is horizontally scalable with less pain incase your application needs to scale up.

```
var companyName = new SqlParameter("@company_name", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = variable_name};
var oReturnObjects = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<ClassName>(
                "spa_Test1 @company_name", companyName);
```

More links:

- [Does Entity Framework Code First support stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845246/does-entity-framework-code-first-support-stored-procedures)
- [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first)

Comment: Thanks brykneval! ill try it

Comment: public virtual ObjectResult<Test1_Result> Test1(string company_name)
        {
            var company_nameParameter = company_name != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("company_name", company_name) :
                new ObjectParameter("company_name", typeof(string));
    
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Test1_Result>("Test1", company_nameParameter);
        }

Comment: Hello again this is the method created in EF context . I suppose  i need  now to create  a class with this method (new model)  and an instance-object (new controller)??can you guide-help?